# MSSQL sa user properties shows locked out while loginproperty('sa','isLocked') shows 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

When looking at the 'sa' user properties the Status page shows 'Login is locked out' with a check in the box. When I run tsql "SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('sa','IsLocked'); it returns 0 (false).

Yes 'Enforce password policy' is enabled on the 'sa' user properties General page.

If I do an alter user and disable the password policy it never reflects on the status page of the user properties.

Comment: First, are you sure your query window is connected to the same server as Object Explorer? If so, which one is actually true? Can you log in as `sa`? What happens if you refresh Object Explorer and navigate to that UI again? Generally I distrust the flaky GUI panels, but especially when they disagree with something the server is telling me directly.

Comment: @I'm going through and verifying everything again. I'm beginning to think it's a flaky GUI and I chased a rabbit for no reason on it. I went through the same troubleshooting steps that you outlined prior to posting this question and was getting odd results. I've since moved to another chunk of servers testing it and I'm getting different results. I'm going to close my question until I can find get more detail on what is happening.